VBA - workbook_open crushes macro that worked before but works fine when run manually
I have a code that did work but then stopped for some users and now, after some time, also for me most of the time. It does not work when automatically run when opening excel, but it does work when I run it myself. I receive error 1004. Macro is placed in ThisWorkbook module. Please help to find the reason for the issue.
Code is supposed to remove password from workbook and unhide two tabs once it verifies that it is one of the users listed in tab Access. Debugger stops at:
LastRow = Worksheets("Access").Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Full code:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim UserName As String
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

UserName = LCase(Environ$("username"))
LastRow = Worksheets("Access").Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
myArray = Worksheets("Access").Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
ReDim myArray(1 To LastRow) As Integer
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If LCase(Worksheets("Access").Range("A" & i).Value) = UserName Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "Pswd1"
            Sheets("Reward").Visible = True
            Sheets("Pivot").Visible = True
            GoTo TUTAJ
        End If
    Next i
    
TUTAJ:
    
End Sub


As it might matter, there is another code running in that file BeforeSave, that hides two tabs previously unhidden and adds paswword on workoob. It works fine:
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim UserName As String
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

UserName = LCase(Environ$("username"))
LastRow = Worksheets("Access").Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
myArray = Worksheets("Access").Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
ReDim myArray(1 To LastRow) As Integer
    
On Error GoTo WYJSCIE
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If LCase(Worksheets("Access").Range("A" & i).Value) = UserName Then
            Sheets("Reward").Visible = False
            Sheets("Pivot").Visible = False
            ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="Pswd1", Structure:=True, Windows:=False
            GoTo TUTAJ
        End If
    Next i
    
WYJSCIE:
TUTAJ:

End Sub

Tried to :

remove ReDim myArray(1 To LastRow) As Integer and adding .value after myArray = Worksheets("Access").Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
enabling all macros without asking in excel options
delaying this macro by adding:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "ThisWorkbook.RunMacro"
End Sub
and renaming my main macro to RunMacro. In this scenario debugger stopped at this line
making macros public
removing code, saving file and pressing Debug -> CompileVBA Project, saving and reopening file
running file from shared drive as well as from local drive
going through internet and copilot for 8 hours looking for solution


I can't see anything in that line that would give Application-defined or object-defined error.  If the Access worksheet didn't exist you'd get a Subscript out of range.  It shouldn't make any difference in this case, but try adding ThisWorkbook.   So ThisWorkbook. Worksheets("Access").Range("A:A").....

thanks for such a fast answer. Unfortunately adding ThisWorkbook changed nothing. I even restarted PC after that change - still stops at this line.

It's a longshot, but try changing LastRow = Worksheets("Access").Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row to LastRow = Worksheets("Access").Range("A:A").Cells(Worksheets("Access").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

there is a change! Now it crushes but on line 'code'ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "Pswd1"'code' . When run by myself, code still works just fine.

what is even more, I have another excel.xlsm file on network drive next to the one with problem, it uses almost exactly the same code and it works like a charm

Couple of things I've just noticed.  Error handling should occur outside of the main body of code.  After your Next i line add Exit Sub - this identifies the end of the main body.  Your GoTo TUTAJ line is telling the code to exit the For...Next loop.   Replace that line with Exit For instead and delete the TUTAJ label.  Also, the ActiveWorkbook when that line runs would be the workbook containing the code, so better to use ThisWorkbook instead.

It does sound like the crash is occurring due to more than one workbook being open. Darren's suggestion may well help or use static references to the book(s) set at the start.

SOLVED - combining together advice from CLR and Darren Bartrup-Cook made it work! Thank you :)

to complete the picture - I had only one excel opened, and in the past, when it worked, it did not matter how many excels were opened. Thank you once more for your help!
